# discord.js bot is deleting all messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the following code running in my bot, as a command that deletes cuss words. However, it seems to make the bot delete any message that's sent no matter what! HELP!

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.includes == 'bannedWord1' ||'bannedWord2' || 'bannedWord3' || 'bannedWord4') {
       message.delete(1);
       message.channel.send("That word's not appropriate!");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, Max Vollmer. I didn't notice I hadn't changed the code.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `message.content.includes == 'bannedWord1' ||'bannedWord2' || 'bannedWord3' || 'bannedWord4'` really means `(message.content.includes == 'bannedWord1') ||'bannedWord2' || 'bannedWord3' || 'bannedWord4'`. Non-empty strings are truthy so this is always true.

Also, I assume `message.content` is a string. So you need to handle things like 'assumptions' which contains `ass` but isn't a bad word.

Demo solution:

```js
var badWords = [
  'bannedWord1',
  'bannedWord2',
  'bannedWord3',
  'bannedWord4'
];

var contents = [
  'This is a test.',
  'bannedWord1 tester.',
  'bannedWord2!',
  'OkaywordthatcontainsbannedWord1.'
];

var allowed = contents.filter(content => {
  var words = content.toLowerCase().trim().match(/\w+|\s+|[^\s\w]+/g);
  return !words.find(word => {
    return badWords.includes(word);
  });
});

console.log(allowed);
```

Use in your case:

```
var badWords = [
  'bannedWord1',
  'bannedWord2',
  'bannedWord3',
  'bannedWord4'
];

bot.on('message', message => {
  var words = message.content.toLowerCase().trim().match(/\w+|\s+|[^\s\w]+/g);
  var containsBadWord = words.some(word => {
    return badWords.includes(word);
  });
  if (containsBadWord) {
    message.delete(1);
    message.channel.send("That word's not appropriate!");
  }
});
```

Regex explanation from regex101.com

1. 1st Alternative `\w+`

   - `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2. 2nd Alternative `\S+`

   - `\S+` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
3. 3rd Alternative `[^\s\w]+`

   - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\s\w]+`
   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) \s matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v]`)

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense and is very helpful. I am kind of confused by what the .match(/\w+|\S...) part is doing, though.

Comment: I added a regex explanation. Basically, the goal is to split the string into words. These words may be separated by spaces, certain punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to compare pointer to function with expression 
`string OR string OR string`
which always is true so the if executed for each new message

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have.. feel free to mess around with it!

```
bot.on('message', async message => {


  //1 blacklisted words
  let blacklisted = ['bannedWord1','bannedWord2,','bannedWord3','bannedWord4','bannedWord5','bannedWord6','bannedWord7','bannedWord8','bannedWord9','bannedWord10','bannedWord11'] //words

  //2 looking for words
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) { // loops through the blacklisted list
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }
  // checks casesensitive words

  //3 deletes and send message
    if (foundInText) {
      message.delete();
      message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:').then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
  }
});
```